# Find non zero value in column G on sheet 1, return value of Column C in that row to sheet 2 (VBA)

Tags: vba, excel

My first sheet is set up like this:

[image]

1. I want to find the non zero values in column G. Then I want to read the corresponding name in column C. I, then, want to return the value of the name to a cell on Sheet 2.
2. At this point, it doesn't matter what cell it returns to in sheet 2.  It sounds like a VLOOKUP or INDEXMATCH but my VBA isn't good enough to figure out the formatting of it. This is some code that I tried and I can get it to return the name. But I don't know how to do it for all non zeros or how to have it print to sheet 2. Need a loop or need to figure out look ups!

code:

```
For Each c In Range("G6").Cells

  If c.Value > 0 Then

    PlayerName = Range(Cells(Selection.Row, 3).Address).Value

End If

Exit For

Next c
```

Comment: Compare to which column on Sheet2?

Comment: Hi Scott, not comparing to a column on sheet 2. I just want it to print the value of the name in column A to anywhere on sheet 2. So far I have something like the code shown in my question but I need to either incorporate a loop or figure out the lookup functions...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code will find the first row which has a number greater than 0 in column G (starting at row 6), and write the value in column C of that row to cell X5 of Sheet2.

```
With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    For Each c In .Range("G6", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp)).Cells
        If c.Value > 0 Then
            Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(5, "X").Value = c.Offset(0, -4).Value

            Exit For ' Moved this inside the `If`, otherwise it will exit as soon as
                     ' the first cell in the range is processed, irrespective of whether
                     ' it was greater than 0 or not
        End If
    Next c
End With
```

---

Iterative version:

```
Dim s2Row as Long
s2Row = 5
With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    For Each c In .Range("G6", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp)).Cells
        If c.Value > 0 Then
            Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(s2Row, "X").Value = c.Offset(0, -4).Value
            s2Row = s2Row + 1
        End If
    Next c
End With
```

Comment: This is great start! Thank you. How can I make this iterate so it finds all values greater than zero and prints the associated name?

Comment: @Astronut11 Remove the `Exit For`, and change `5` to be a variable, and increment that variable each time you write something (or don't increment the variable if you just want to keep writing to the same cell - that's a bit pointless though)

Comment: Yes! This is perfect. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the logic you'll need.  Will you be able to build the macro with this logic?  It will help you understand how to maneuver rows that are greater than zero.  Then you copy the column on that row y9ou need and paste it to the other sheet.

```
Sub macro1()
Dim myRng As Range, lastRow As Long


lastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("G65536").End(xlUp).Row

Set myRng = Sheet1.Range("G1:G" & lastRow)

For Each Rng In myRng
    If IsNumeric(Rng.Value) And Rng.Value > 0 Then
        Debug.Print "Cell " & Rng.Address & " has the number " & Rng.Value & " in row " & Rng.Row
    End If
Next Rng




End Sub
```

Comment: Hi John, this is a great starting point! Thank you. I think I am following the logic. We select all of row G, then find the last row. Starting at G1 it searches down and if the value is a number greater than 0 it prints the address, value and row. How do I navigate to the column that contains the name using this row in order to copy?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, except "G" is a column, not a row.  Replace the debug.print line with WorkSheets("sheet name to copy from here").Rows(rng.row).Copy Destination:=WorkSheets("sheet name to copy to here").Range("A" & rowCounterVariable).  Of course, change the sheet names to your actual sheet names.

Here I set the first row at 2 on the page to copy to.  If you need to set it to the first available row then you need to research how to find the last used row on that page.  Put these exact terms into Google "VBA EXCEL HOW TO FIND LAST USED ROW".  I have an example of finding the last used row for the activesheet inside the code.  We could give you fish today, and teach you how to fish.  But you need to catch your own.  We're not here to write code for you.

```
Sub macro2()
Dim myRng As Range, lastRow As Long, rowCounterVariable as long

rowCounterVariable = 2
lastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("G65536").End(xlUp).Row

Set myRng = Sheet1.Range("G1:G" & lastRow)

For Each Rng In myRng
    If IsNumeric(Rng.Value) And Rng.Value > 0 Then
       WorkSheets("sheet name to copy from here").Rows(rng.row).Copy Destination:=WorkSheets("sheet name to copy to here").Range("A" & rowCounterVariable)
         rowCounterVariable = rowCounterVariable + 1
    End If
Next Rng


End Sub
```